In excel I have a date in column C and want to ensure this date doesn't occur between column A and column B
I have a date (1/5/2023) in Column C and want to ensure that this date doesn't occur between Column A (12/2/2022) and Column B (1/3/2023) and the equation will be spit out to Column D. Obviously for this we can see it doesn't occur between, but this is a large data set and I want to check for all rows.
I need an equation to solve for this. I tried a VLookup but didn't come up with anything. This could be a skill issue with excel.

Assuming you want to compare the date in column C with the dates in columns A and B on the same row: IF(AND(C1>A1,C1<B1),"Between","Not between"). If not, then some sample data, the expected result, as well as the VLOOKUP you have tried would be useful

Do you want the specific date to be found? Say you have 29/04/23 and 02/05/23 in your list, is that a reason to check it off? Is your data in order? Are column A and B only dates? Some more explanation of your data sample and what exactly you want would be nice.

Why not a simple Match()?
